# Date parameter using with stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to retrieve data in *iReport* using stored procedure(SP) in SQL Server 2008.

My stored procedure uses two parameters `Date_From` & `Date_To`. I would like to run the report in specified (by these parameters) period but in any case I have info like "No data in report". In table the date is stored in format "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000". both of the parameters are set as "java.util.Date". In the Report query I have:

- Query language = plsql
- In query window: `Name_of_procedure $P{Date_From}, $P{Date_To}`

I found somewhere info that is possible to change the Date format and I have change it to:
Date format "yyyy-MM-dd", but after this change, instead of generate the report iReport is coming back to the Designer window, without any error or info.

May I ask for help, how to correct set the parameter that would provide the Date in format "yyyy-MM-dd"?

iReport version: 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

To see the error you can go to Window--> Report Output option there you can find the error.

To call the procedure syntax should be

```
  CALL  Name_of_procedure ( $P{Date_From}, $P{Date_To})
```

and to set the default value for parameters you can use this syntax.

```
   new  Date(114,7,06)  --> to set default date as 06 Aug 2014.
```

Comment: Sharad, thank you for suggestion. I couldn't check it because was out of ofice. Using the "CALL  Name_of_procedure ( $P{Date_From}, $P{Date_To})" cause error like "Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'". I used the SQL Profiler on the server to examine what exactly the iReport sendining to SQL, below is the result:  `declare @p1 int
set @p1=5
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 datetime,@P1 datetime',N'Rpt__DepSumM @P0, @P1                ','1970-01-01 13:46:42','1970-01-01 13:46:44.297'
select @p1
go `

Comment: It is little starnge if I chose today's date